# Why can't interfaces have static initialization block when it can have static methods alone?

Tags: java, static, static-initialization, static-block

After java 8 it is known that interfaces can have static methods and default methods.

**Below is the example :**

```
interface interA{
    static void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Static method inside interface");
    }
    public default void AImp(){
        System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interA");
    }
}
```

Now my question is that why is static initialization block not allowed in interface.?

**Example :**

```
interface interA{
    static void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Static method inside interface");
    }
    static
    {
    }
    public default void AImp(){
        System.out.println("Calling Aimp from interA");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to initialize in the block?

Comment: Why are you providing implementation of methods in interfere? 
Interfce holds only signature of methods.

Comment: @ParthPatel - As of Java 8, interfaces can have [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Comment: I agree, with the addition of `default` methods the difference between interfaces and 'real' classes has become less obvious. Java started out with ensuring a single inheritance tree, and interfaces were [adopted from Objective-C's](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html) equivalent [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). With default methods, interfaces seem to become classes.

Comment: (@SushmiS - Ignore my earlier, deleted comment, copy/paste error.)

Comment: @luk2302 I may want to print anything inside the block . My question is that why is it not allowing Static initialization block but allowing static methods alone.